# how to make a graph fit with layout on android

Tags: android, achartengine

i'm very new to Android and AChartengine and i'm working in my project.

Assume i have a Layout like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/displayECG"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="100px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And in MainActivity.java i code like:

```
view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataSet, renderer);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayECG);
layout.addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

But when i run my App and i got a graph, it very smaller than layout space. I want a graph, it fits with my layout, so how can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Can't see anything that's obviously wrong. When in MainActivity are you adding the graph?

Comment: on Create function of Activity, i tried many solution but it still not work. Hic

Comment: ah, that might be the problem. move that code to onResume where the system has actually determined the layout. oncreate is too early in the activity's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart is actually filling up the whole layout, but by default AChartEngine has a lot of extras turned on. I would suggest adding the following lines prior to creating the chart:

```
renderer.setLegendHeight(1);
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
renderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0});
```

There may be a couple other things you need, but this should at least get you started. Also, your `displayECG` is only 100 px tall. That may be limiting as well.

Comment: yes, the problem is "setMargins". And i fixed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the ChartFactory.

But from the layout perspective your giving a hight of 100px to the nested LinearLayout, try using wrap_content instead.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/displayECG"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

   </LinearLayout>
```

Also, try calling invalidate on the layout after you add the child view for it to redraw itself:

```
view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataSet, renderer);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayECG);
layout.addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.invalidate();
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for reply me. I tried but it still not worked.

Comment: My App has many layout, so when i applied solution like you, it  obscured the remaining layout.